# ActiveMQ inactivity timeout

Tags: activemq-classic

I am using ActiveMQ version 5.10.0 with default configuration. 
The documentation on Active MQ transport protocols say that by default wireFormat.maxInactivityDuration is 30000 and transport.useKeepAlive is enabled by default.

Does that mean that for default configuration , inactivity timeout will never occur ? as keepAlive messages are enabled and sent by default ?

I have tried leaving my queues idle for a day and I did not see any Inactivity timeout logs.

But the activeMQ page also says
" Using the default values; if no data has been written or read from the connection for 30 seconds, the InactivityMonitor kicks in. The InactivityMonitor throws an InactivityIOException and shuts down the transport associated with the connection."

http://activemq.apache.org/activemq-inactivitymonitor.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The inactivity timeout would occur when the connection is broken or the broker is experiencing issues such that it cannot respond to the ping request that the client will send it.  The timeout does not related to message inactivity or the like but to ping / pong type hearbeats between client and broker.  So long as the broker is healthy and sending the requested responses the client will not terminate the connection even if no messages happen to be flowing across it.